# Where could I find the reference for the statement of Euler finding out the coefficients of Fourier series?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I am reading Carlslaw's "[Introduction to the Theory of Fourier's Series and Integrals](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Fourier_s.html?id=fHdVAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)", first chapter on the history of Fourier series, page 3. The author asserts that Clairaut and Euler did derive in parts the coefficients of Fourier series. He said Euler wrote:

$$f(x)=a_0+2a_1\cos(x)+2a_2\cos(2x)+...2a_n(\cos(n)$$

Euler multipled both sides $\cos(nx)$ and integrated the series from $0$ to $\pi$ term by term to obtain:

$$a_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$

His reference is Petrop.N.Acta, 11, 1793(1798), page 94 (May 1777).

I checked it and find "[Methodus facilis inveniendi series per sinus sosinusve angulorum multiplorum procedentes, quarum usus in universa theoria astronomiae est amplissimus](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1702&context=euler-works)". I think this is the correct paper, but I cannot find the reference that the author made.

In that article, I only see on page 101, this:

$$S=1+\cos(x)+\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)+...$$

Multiply by $2\sin(\frac{x}{2})$

One get:

$$2\sin(\frac{x}{2})S=2\sin(\frac{x}{2})+2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(x)+2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(2x)+2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(3x)+...$$

$$2\sin(\frac{x}{2})S=2\sin(\frac{x}{2})+\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)-\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)+\sin(\frac{5}{2}x)-\sin(\frac{5}{2}x)...+\sin(n+\frac{1}{2}x)-\sin(n-\frac{1}{2}x)$$

This is on page 101.

I couldn't find the reference for this integral, can you help me to find it?

Answer (score 3):

Euler's calculation of Fourier series coefficients appears in his paper
*De serierum determinatione seu nova methodus inveniendi terminos generales serierum* from 1753.  A link to it on the Euler archive is https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/189/: see the second pdf link at the bottom, on page 81, which is the end of the solution to Problem IX just above Corollary I.

A cleaner scan from the *Opera Omnia* (Series I, volume 14, p. 511) is on the Hathitrust website https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=pst.000010974780&view=1up&seq=527 (this link may not work everywhere). See the equation just before Corollary 1 on that page.